# How can a Jenkins build differentiate between a SCM-triggered, and a user-requested build?

Tags: version-control, build, triggers, hudson, jenkins

I would like my builds to behave differently (a handling script needs to know) if a person requested the build through the UI "build now" button, or if it was triggered by SCM.  I don't want to have to provide a checkbox in the UI that the users have to alter - I've already gotten blowback from them about such things.  Trouble is, any parameter I set has the same default regardless of how the build is triggered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not really have 1 job with different behaviour. If you need different behaviour set up a job per behaviour. Best bet in your case is to have 2 separate jobs, one for the SCM triggered builds, and one for the manually triggered builds.

There's a plugin to allow you to filter jobs into separate pages (can't remember the name at the moment). You could set all SCM builds on 1 page and manual builds on another, then set the manual build page as the default one on login. Users will only see the jobs you want triggered manually by default, but can still access the SCM triggered builds by selecting the other page.

Answer (score 0):

Could you somehow check the SCM polling log during the pre-build (with a script), and then go from there?